# Displaying Routes on Maps with OpenRoute Service and Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, openrouteservice

For my internship, I'm currently working on creating a route planner. I'm utilizing OpenRoute Service and Leaflet for this project. While I can generate a route successfully, I encounter a funny issue when trying to display the route on a map—it appears in the ocean! I've attempted to resolve this by providing center coordinates and potentially a boundary box (bbx). What am I doing wrong here, and can someone assist me?

[image: this is how it looks like]

```
function calculateRoute() {
extractAndConvertToCoordinates().then(() => {
    let coordinatesArray = [];

    if (startPointCoordinates.length === 0) {
        getStartPointCoordinates(sPostcode, sStraatnaam, sHuisnummer).then((startPointCoordinates) => {
            coordinatesArray.push(startPointCoordinates);
            coordinatesArray.push.apply(coordinatesArray, tableCoordinates);

            if (endPointCoordinates && endPointCoordinates.length !== 0) {
                coordinatesArray.push(endPointCoordinates);
            }

            sendRequest(coordinatesArray);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching start point coordinates:', error);
        });
    } else {
        coordinatesArray.push(startPointCoordinates);
        coordinatesArray.push.apply(coordinatesArray, tableCoordinates);

        if (endPointCoordinates && endPointCoordinates.length !== 0) {
            coordinatesArray.push(endPointCoordinates);
        }

        sendRequest(coordinatesArray);
    }
});
}

function sendRequest(coordinatesArray) {
let requestBody = {
    coordinates: coordinatesArray
};

let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
let transport = document.getElementById('SelectedVehicle').value;
request.open('POST', 'https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/' + transport + '/geojson');
request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json, application/geo+json, application/gpx+xml, img/png; charset=utf-8');
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', api);
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log('Status:', this.status);
        console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
        console.log('Body:', this.responseText);

        let routeData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        let routeCoordinates = routeData.features[0].geometry.coordinates;

        let centerCoordinates = [52.1326, 5.2913]; // Netherlands center coordinates

        let map = L.map('map').setView(centerCoordinates, 12);

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        L.polyline(routeCoordinates, { color: 'green' }).addTo(map);

        map.fitBounds(L.polyline(routeCoordinates).getBounds());
    }
};
request.send(JSON.stringify(requestBody));
}
```